# Express - Serve different static folders on same route

Tags: javascript, express

Hello I would like to serve two different front-end applications on same route.

User will send a token in HTTP header and based on the information that token holds application should decide which folder should it serve statically. Is that possible?

I already have a middleware that parses token and provides me with user role.

Preferred behavior would be

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/admin' function(req, res) {
        if(req.headers.security.role === 1) {
           // serve superadmin page
        } else if(req.headers.security.role === 2) {
           // serve user page 
        } else {
            // serve forbidden page
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: @hjpotter92 could you please tell me how to do this

Comment: Write a middleware, which parses your `req.headers` to see the token, and accordingly serve the files.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I already have a middleware that does that. I have updated my question

Comment: use connect-roles with server side stored session(RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session), ). Use that session to find the user and his roles.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, here is an example with a cookie sent with the request with nodejs.

```
app.get('*', function (request, response, next) {
   let app = request.cookies.app;
   if (app) {
     response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.html')) 
   } else {
     response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'app2.html')) 
   }
});
```

Comment: This serves two different files. But I have two big react apps that should be served. So it has a full folder structure behind it.

Comment: Do your apps use react router, or the server handles the routing? Because if the react handles the routing, all you need is the root index file for the app.

Comment: React will handle routing in application but if i serve index.html can i include js files or maybe custom css files?

Comment: Yes, you serve 2 different html files, each one has it's own js and css files, where the js file will be the react app, so I think that is everything you need.